# php preg_match_all results from (numerical) STRING to DECIMAL - type

Tags: php, string, decimal, preg-match-all

I have script that identifies with `preg_match_all` some numbers from a given file and in a given format `'#(\d\,\d\d\d\d)#'` (decimal, with 4 decimals). With them, later, I need to do some math operations to find out the sum, average etc.

With `print_r` I can see all matches from the array and it is ok (4,3456, 4,9098, etc.). I verify the type of variables and `gettype()` returned **string**

Unfortunately I cannot do math operations with them because when I use the variables in a math expression the result is always rounded regardless of what came afer the comma.

For example:

4,3456 + 4,9098 + 4,3456 = 12, or 12,0000 -- if I use `number_format`.

I used `.` instead of `,` in the numbers, I formatted the results with `number_format`, but have had no success. It seems I am missing something.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens even before the number_format call -- PHP considers `.` as the decimal separator, not `,`. you need to str_replace all your array elements:

```
$values_array = str_replace(",", ".", $values_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses the `.` character as decimal separator, so you have to replace the `,` by a `.` in your matched numbers before converting them to numbers:

```
$number = floatval(strtr("1,234", ",", "."));
// 1.234
```

Example:

```
<?php

$numbers = array("1,234", "5,67");
$numbers = str_replace(",", ".", $numbers);
echo number_format($numbers[0] + $numbers[1], 4, ',', ' ');
```

Try it here: http://codepad.org/LeeTiKPF

Comment: He must have done something wrong; "1.24"+1 gives 2.24, not 2.